# hive drop table on a condition

Tags: bash, hive, hiveql, oozie, impala

I have two tables old_table and new_table. They differ only in row count. I wana drop the old_table if row count is less than new_table. 
How can I acehive this?

In hive or as a shell script in oozie?

Following is something I am trying to acheive : 
new  = select count(*) from new_table ;
old = select count(*) from old_table ;

if new > old then drop old_table ;

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with a bash script, for example something like this (not tested) :

```
new=$(hive -e 'select count(*) from new_table')
old=$(hive -e 'select count(*) from old_table')
echo "old : $old, new : $new"
if (( new > old )); then
  hive -e 'drop table old_table'
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, I created oozie workflow and added sh file and echo the new and old but both returned blank values.

Comment: `echo the new and old` How exactly did you it ?

Comment: # #Wed Nov 01 17:07:59 EDT 2017 old= new=

Comment: sh file : new=$(hive -e 'select count(*) from b');
echo new;
old=$(hive -e 'select count(*) from a')
echo old;

Comment: this is not how you print variables in bash, you forgot the `$`. I edited my answer to show you how

Comment: sh data:new=$(hive -e 'select count(*) from a')
old=$(hive -e 'select count(*) from b')
echo "old : $old, new : $new"                                                                              output- # #Wed Nov 01 17:30:37 EDT 2017 old=, new \:

Comment: Thanks for the help but I still get blank.

Comment: You have to write `select count(*) from a` to get the total number of rows. Just try to run these queries in Hive before you run them in a bash script.

Comment: The star is there in the query but when i paste it here it doesnt appear , may be because of java. I tried in hive already and it does return value. old is 50 new is 100.

Comment: i tried in .hql file (oozie)  !connect jdbc:hive2://sda1node04..:10000/default dummy dummy org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
use p_poc_ccts2;
if (${new_cnt}>${old_cnt}, drop table old,echo 'na') ;   but I get error: Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'if' '(' '100' (state=42000,code=40000)